# Add date to excel file name

Tags: batch-file

I want to add system date in MMDDYYYY format after second delimiter (~) to all my excel files in particular directory. It would be basically renaming of file.

Example-

Orginal Name-

`Canada_report~D~.xls`

Expected Output-

`Canada_report~D~05312013.xls`

We can set date in `MMDDYYY` as below but not sure how to append it to all excel files (after second delimiter `~`) which are available in particular directory

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do set THEDATE=%%e%%f%%
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should rename all *.xls files in the current folder, adding the d8 variable to the position before the .xls extension.

You may consider using a YYYYMMDD format that sorts correctly in a folder and is the preferred date format for that reason. Getting the date in a reliable and robust way is very easy with Wmic.

Here is a way using WMIC to set the d8 variable (XP Pro and higher) - and it can also be used for a MMDDYYYY format.

Change the `F:\FOLDER` to your path.  Test it on a sample folder first.

```
:: timestamp YYYYMMDD
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set d8=%dt:~0,8%
pushd "F:\FOLDER"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir *.xls /b /a-d ') do ren "%%a" "%%~na%d8%%%~xa"
popd
pause
```

To get MMDDYYYY format change this line

set d8=%dt:~0,8%

to

set d8=%dt:~4,2%%dt:~6,2%%dt:~0,4%

Comment: can you pls tell me whats wrong in running below command on cmd    for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %d in ("%date%") do echo set THEDATE=%e%f%g for /f "delims=" %a in ('Canada_report~D~.xls /b /a-d ') do echo ren "%a" "%%~na%THEDATE%%%~xa"

Comment: There are a few problems.  You are mixing command line and batch % characters.  You are echoing THEDATE instead of setting the variable.  Try the batch file I gave you, which is not destructive.

Comment: Renaming not working for file stored in my M:\Test1 path with below script..                                                       @echo off
set d8=20130531
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('M:\Test1*.xls /b /a-d ') do ren "%%a" "%%~na%d8%%%~xa"

Comment: with your script it got it worked..but why after giving directory path its not working? Also i dont want to set hardcoded value for date ..

Comment: You can use your dynamic method for the date but don't include `echo` in your set command - and it depends on the computer regional settings.  The WMIC method is region independent.  For the rename, there are two ways to specify a path.  One is to add /s to the DIR command `as long as the folder doesn't contain subdirectories.`

Comment: I have changed the code above - using PUSHD will allow you to set your folder.

Comment: Thanks Foxidrive..Its working but cmd prompting to press any key for renaming file..can it be avoided please..

Comment: Working perfectly..Last question pls..can you please let me know how to get MMDDYYYY through wmic

Comment: Hello foxidirve..I want to execute this batch script on network shared location like path "\\gpri11\KAM\"..can there be some modifications done to above script to avoid issues of UNC path not supported? Please suggest

Comment: `net use z: \\server\share\folder` this command will set drive z: to the UNC path and you may need to add password etc.  Then you can use `PUSHD "Z:\" in the batch file.